# How to implement a "Citation" table? (using SQLModel or SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, sqlmodel

I'm struggling with implementing the concept of "scientific paper citation" in SQL.

I have a table of `Paper`s. Each `Paper` can ***cite*** many other `Paper`s and, vice-versa, it can ***be cited*** by many other more.

Here's the code I wrote

```py
class Paper(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None,  primary_key=True)
    bibliography: List["Citation"] = Relationship(back_populates="citing")
    cited_by: List["Citation"] = Relationship(back_populates="cited")

class Citation(SQLModel, table=True):
    citing_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, foreign_key="paper.id")
    citing: "Paper" = Relationship(back_populates="bibliography")
    cited_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, foreign_key="paper.id")
    cited: "Paper" = Relationship(back_populates="cited_by")
```

This is not working:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Paper.bibliography - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

The problem is the fact that I wrote `foreign_key="paper.id"` twice, but I don't know how to fix it.

---

To reproduce the error:

- I'm using Python 3.10.5;
- the only dependency is `sqlmodel`.

```py
from typing import List
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import create_engine
from sqlmodel import Field
from sqlmodel import Relationship
from sqlmodel import Session
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

sqlite_file_name = "database.db"
sqlite_url = f"sqlite:///{sqlite_file_name}" 
engine = create_engine(sqlite_url, echo=True)

# class Paper(SQLModel, table=True): ...

# class Citation(SQLModel, table=True): ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Paper()
```

I'm using [`SQLModel`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/), but an answer in [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling multiple possible `JOIN` conditions in SQLAlchemy is documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html). The solution is to explicitly pass the [`foreign_keys`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys) argument to your `RelationshipProperty` constructor.

In this case, you will need to specify that for *all four* relationships in question.

Since SQLModel currently does not allow to directly pass *all* available relationship arguments to its constructor (though I am working on a PR for that), you need to utilize the `sa_relationship_kwargs` parameter.

Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel


class Paper(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    bibliography: list["Citation"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="citing",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"foreign_keys": "Citation.citing_id"},
    )
    cited_by: list["Citation"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="cited",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"foreign_keys": "Citation.cited_id"},
    )

class Citation(SQLModel, table=True):
    citing_id: Optional[int] = Field(
        default=None,
        primary_key=True,
        foreign_key="paper.id",
    )
    citing: Paper = Relationship(
        back_populates="bibliography",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"foreign_keys": "Citation.citing_id"},
    )
    cited_id: Optional[int] = Field(
        default=None,
        primary_key=True,
        foreign_key="paper.id",
    )
    cited: Paper = Relationship(
        back_populates="cited_by",
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"foreign_keys": "Citation.cited_id"},
    )
```

As a side note, I think in this case it might be even nicer to use an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to have an additional direct link from a paper to all papers it is cited by and citing (without the additional "hop" via the `Citation` object), but I believe this is currently not possible with SQLModel.

Comment: Thank you very much @Daniil! I already started to explore SQLModel source code and found `sa_relationship_kwargs` but didn't know how to properly use it. Thank you again and good luck for your PR :)